# How to restrict https google cloud function to users who just paid for a subscription

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function which grants a user a premium subscription token as follows:

```
exports.addPremiumUser = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    // get user and add custom claim 
    return admin.auth().getUserByEmail(data.email).then(user => {
        return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, {
            premium: true
        })
    }).then(() => {
        return {
            message: `Success! ${data.email} has been made a Premium user`
        }
    }).catch(error => {
        return error
    })
})
```

Typically I would authenticate the caller (like making sure they are an admin) like this:

```
    // check request is made by admin
    if ( context.auth.token.admin !== true ) {
        return { error: 'only admins can add SMEs'}
    }
```

I haven't been able to come up with a good way to authenticate callers of this function. I want this function to only be callable by someone who has just paid for the premium subscription. With my current implementation any user could call this function and get a premium subscription for free. I am sure there is someone out there who has implemented tokens for subscriptions so I am wanting to know what is the way that I should secure this.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good idea to allow users to invoke code for themselves that **unconditionally** modify their own custom claims for enhanced privileges.

What you should do instead is have some other backend code (that can't be directly invoked by the user) that sets the custom claims at the time when it's known they should have those privileges.  *Since we don't know at what point a user has paid for a subscription, it's not possible to say what's going to work for your case.*  You're going to have to figure that out by analyzing the flow of data through your system, and come up with some sort of trigger that will add the custom claims.  Whatever system you're using for subscriptions will have to be hooked into.

Comment: Thanks I am going to look into this. I assumed that I would probably have to change the implementation entirely.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for this in the context of a firebase app? My backend is firebase.

Comment: As I said, I don't know the system you're using for subscriptions.  You should consult its documentation.